# In a ring $R$, how to prove the following results?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Problem: In a ring $R$ and $a,b\in R$, prove the following :

(i) $m(na)=n(ma)=(mn)a$, where $m,n$ are positive integers.
(ii) $(ma).(nb)=(na).(mb)=(mn)(a.b)$, where $m,n$ are positive integers.

I have tried in the following way:
$m(na)=[na+na+\dots+na]$(m times)
$=\underbrace{[\underbrace{(a+a+\dots+a)}_\text{$n$ times}+\underbrace{(a+a+\dots+a)}_\text{$n$ times}+ \dots+\underbrace{(a+a+\dots+a)}_\text{$n$ times}]}_\text{$m$ times}$

$=\underbrace{(a+a+\dots+a)}_\text{$mn$ times}$
$=(mn)a$

Is my approach correct? If yes then what will be for (ii)?

Answer (score 1):

Induction to show that $m(na) = (mn)a$.

Let $m\geq 0$ be arbitrary.

$n=0$: $m(0a) = 0 = (m0)a$.

$n\geq 0$. $m((n+1)a) = m(na +a) =m(na) + ma = (by ind.) (mn)a + ma = (mn+m)a = (m(n+1))a$.

This requires to check that zero (in a comm. ring) is absorbing: $0a=0$ (holds for the ring of integers).

It also requires the definition of $n$-fold of a ring element:

$1a=a$ and $(n+1)a=na+a$ for each $n\geq 1$.